# Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large error

Tags: haskell

**update1:**

after tried a new way to do 2d array's access, it can not use bracket of bracket

```
let allparams = replicateM 3 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
let alltrees = [getAllTrees c | x <- allparams, c <- [x]]
let alltrees1 = [b | c <- alltrees | x <- [c] | b <- [d | ee <- alltrees | y <- [ee] | d <- ((x,y), eeval1(x) >= eeval1(y) && eeval2(x) >= eeval2(y) && eeval3(x) >= eeval3(y) && eeval4(x) >= eeval4(y))]]


<interactive>:8:36:
    Unexpected parallel statement in a list comprehension
    Use -XParallelListComp

<interactive>:8:44: Not in scope: `c'

<interactive>:8:74:
    Unexpected parallel statement in a list comprehension
    Use -XParallelListComp

<interactive>:8:82:
    Not in scope: `ee'
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      `e' (imported from Math.Algebras.VectorSpace),
      e' (imported from Math.Algebras.VectorSpace),
      `e1' (imported from Math.Algebras.VectorSpace)

<interactive>:8:95: Not in scope: `x'

<interactive>:8:97: Not in scope: `y'

<interactive>:8:108: Not in scope: `x'

<interactive>:8:121: Not in scope: `y'

<interactive>:8:134: Not in scope: `x'

<interactive>:8:147: Not in scope: `y'

<interactive>:8:160: Not in scope: `x'

<interactive>:8:173: Not in scope: `y'

<interactive>:8:186: Not in scope: `x'

<interactive>:8:199: Not in scope: `y'
```

got an error when run code below after load :l trees.hs
when make a list of (tree equations , true or false)
and will be filter true or false to display tree equations

before that , after make the list, it has error

```
let allparams = replicateM 3 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
let alltrees = [getAllTrees c | x <- allparams, c <- [x]]
let alltrees1 = forM_ [1..(sizeoflist alltrees)] $ \i -> forM_ [1..(sizeoflist (alltrees!!i))] $ \j -> [(alltrees!!i!!j, eeval1(alltrees!!i!!j) > eeval1(alltrees!!i!!j) && eeval2(alltrees!!i!!j) > eeval2(alltrees!!i!!j) && eeval3(alltrees!!i!!j) > eeval3(alltrees!!i!!j) && eeval4(alltrees!!i!!j) > eeval4(alltrees!!i!!j))]
```

error , how to show items when it is too large

```
*Main> alltrees1!!0
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large
```

trees.hs

```
import Data.List
import Data.Array
--import Data.Set
--import Data.Graph 
import Control.Monad
import Math.Combinat
import Math.Core.Utils
import Math.Core.Field
import Math.Algebras.VectorSpace
import Math.Algebras.Structures
--import Math.CommutativeAlgebra.GroebnerBasis
--import Math.CommutativeAlgebra.Polynomial
--import Math.Algebras.Matrix
import System.IO
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Vertex = Int
type Table a = Array Vertex a
type Graph e = Table [(e, Vertex)]
type Bounds  = (Vertex, Vertex)
type Edge e = (Vertex, e, Vertex)

type Labeling a = Vertex -> a
data LabGraph n e = LabGraph (Graph e) (Labeling n)

data Operation
  = And
  | Or
  | MA
  | MB
  | Impl
    deriving Show

data Mree x
 = Meaf x
 | Mode (Mree x) Operation (Mree x)
   deriving Show

splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)

getAllTrees :: [a] -> [Mree a]
getAllTrees [] = []
getAllTrees [x] = return $ Meaf x
getAllTrees xs = do
  (left, right) <- splits xs
  guard $ not (null left) && not (null right)
  leftT <- getAllTrees left
  rightT <- getAllTrees right
  op <- [MA, MB, And, Or]
  return $ Mode leftT op rightT

eeval1 :: Mree Double -> Double
eeval1 (Meaf x) = x
eeval1 (Mode l And r) = eeval1 l * eeval1 r
eeval1 (Mode l Or r) = eeval1 l + eeval1 r
eeval1 (Mode l MA r) = eeval1 l + eeval1 r
eeval1 (Mode l MB r) = eeval1 l + eeval1 r

eeval2 :: Mree Double -> Double
eeval2 (Meaf x) = x
eeval2 (Mode l And r) = eeval2 l * eeval2 r
eeval2 (Mode l Or r) = eeval2 l + eeval2 r
eeval2 (Mode l MA r) = eeval2 l + eeval2 r
eeval2 (Mode l MB r) = eeval2 l * eeval2 r

eeval3 :: Mree Double -> Double
eeval3 (Meaf x) = x
eeval3 (Mode l And r) = eeval3 l * eeval3 r
eeval3 (Mode l Or r) = eeval3 l + eeval3 r
eeval3 (Mode l MA r) = eeval3 l * eeval3 r
eeval3 (Mode l MB r) = eeval3 l + eeval3 r

eeval4 :: Mree Double -> Double
eeval4 (Meaf x) = x
eeval4 (Mode l And r) = eeval4 l * eeval4 r
eeval4 (Mode l Or r) = eeval4 l + eeval4 r
eeval4 (Mode l MA r) = eeval4 l * eeval4 r
eeval4 (Mode l MB r) = eeval4 l * eeval4 r

sizeoflist :: [a] -> Int
sizeoflist = length
```

Comment: It appears that you have generated an empty list. Does: `null alltrees1` equal `True`?

Comment: BTW, `alltrees = [getAllTrees c | x <- allparams, c <- [x]]` means `alltrees = [getAllTrees x | x <- allparams]` i.e. `alltrees = map getAllTrees allparams`

Comment: List indexing starts at `0`, so `forM_ [1..(sizeoflist alltrees)] $ \i -> ... alltrees !! i` is not going to work. But more generally, you should not use `!!` if you can avoid it. It looks as if you should just be able to use `map`.

Comment: *Main> null alltrees1
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large, it return error , not true

Comment: i change to start from 0 in forM_ still have the same error

Comment: Seriously, don't use `!!` for this. Indexing lists is *slow* as well as error prone. Use `forM_ alltrees` or the like.

Comment: how to use forM_ alltrees without !!? i can not compile after replace  with let alltrees1 = forM_ alltrees $ \i -> forM_ alltrees $ \j -> [(alltrees!!i!!j, eeval1(alltrees!!i!!j) >= eeval1(alltrees!!i!!j) && eeval2(alltrees!!i!!j) >= eeval2(alltrees!!i!!j) && eeval3(alltrees!!i!!j) >= eeval3(alltrees!!i!!j) && eeval4(alltrees!!i!!j) >= eeval4(alltrees!!i!!j))]

Comment: Ørjan is suggesting you apply a list traversal function instead of using indices. If I understand what you're trying to do properly, the best function for you is `map`. Think about what `map (map f) xs` does if `f` is a function and `xs` is a list of lists.

Comment: Why did you completely change an existing question? And I have no idea what you're asking now.

Comment: i forget the original question and try another question

Comment: Well this question already had comments on it which are now irrelevant. You can post a new question, but make it clear what you're asking because this one is quite unclear. And stick to one question at a time, not two as you seem to be asking here.

Comment: I just rolled back the question to its previous form. Ask a new question separately, as a new question.

Comment: reached your question limit, how to increase limit?